# Проблема с зацепкой к WebSocket

Tags: javascript, websocket, chrome-extension, extension, tampermonkey

Возможно, кто то встречался с такой проблемой, что нужно зацепиться на некий WebSocket на сайте для перехвата и отправки сообщений.
Я реализовал полностью рабочий код для скрипта содержимого (content script), и он работает, если его запускать через TamperMonkey. Но если я пытаюсь запихнуть его в свое расширение, то зацепа просто нет. Никаких ошибок, никаких логов, просто пустота. Я подозреваю, что дело может быть в политике безопасности расширений или что то подобное, не сильно разбираюсь в этом. Если кто нибудь знает, как работают расширения, не могли бы, пожалуйста, объяснить, как все же заставить работать его из своего расширения? В браузер загружаю в виде распакованного расширения, из папки. Файлы пока не прикладываю, если вдруг понадобятся какие то листинги, напишите, пожалуйста, в комментариях к вопросу, я максимально быстро их приложу.

Файл манифеста

```
{
"manifest_version": 3,
"name": "asd",
"description": "asd",
"version": "12",
"permissions": [
    "proxy"
],
"icons": {
    "16": "icon16.png",
    "48": "icon48.png",
    "128": "icon128.png"
},

"content_scripts": [
    
    {
        "matches": [
            "https://lichess.org/*"
            
        ],
        "js": [
            "code.js"
        ],
        "css": [
            "style.css"
        ],
        "run_at": "document_start"
    }]
}
```

Функция для установки и подмены сокет-соединения и дальнейшей обработки.

```js
function interceptWebSocket() {

    let webSocket = window.WebSocket;
    const webSocketProxy = new Proxy(webSocket, {
        construct: function (target, args) {
            let wrappedWebSocket = new target(...args);
            webSocketWrapper = wrappedWebSocket;

            wrappedWebSocket.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
                let message = JSON.parse(event.data);
                console.log(message)
    
                if (message.d && typeof message.d.fen === "string" && typeof message.v === "number") {
                    currentFen = message.d.fen;

                    let isWhitesTurn = message.v % 2 == 0;
                    if (isWhitesTurn) {
                        currentFen += " w";
                        curF = "w"
                    } else {;
                        currentFen += " b";
                        curF = "b";
                    }
                    //calculateMove();
                    if(last != move)
                    {webSocketWrapper.send(JSON.stringify({
                      t: "move",
                      d: { u: move, b: 1, l: 100, a: 1 }
                  }));
                  myColor =     get_color();
                  if(curF = myColor[0])
                  {
                                                  last = move;
                  }}

                }
            });
            return wrappedWebSocket;
        }
    });

    window.WebSocket = webSocketProxy;
}
```

Представленный выше код используется в самом скрипте. Следующий код выводит сообщение из сокета по приходу. Он также работает в TamperMonkey, но не работает через расширение.

```js
function interceptWebSocket() {

    let webSocket = window.WebSocket;
    const webSocketProxy = new Proxy(webSocket, {
        construct: function (target, args) {
            let wrappedWebSocket = new target(...args);
            webSocketWrapper = wrappedWebSocket;

            wrappedWebSocket.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
                let message = JSON.parse(event.data);
                console.log(message)
    
            });
            return wrappedWebSocket;
        }
    });

    window.WebSocket = webSocketProxy;
}
```

Скрипт, работающий в TamperMonkey, но не работающий через contentScript

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Test
// @description  1
// @author       1
// @match         *://lichess.org/*
// @run-at        document-start
// @grant         none
// ==/UserScript==
function interceptWebSocket() {

    let webSocket = window.WebSocket;
    const webSocketProxy = new Proxy(webSocket, {
        construct: function (target, args) {
            let wrappedWebSocket = new target(...args);
            webSocketWrapper = wrappedWebSocket;

            wrappedWebSocket.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
                let message = JSON.parse(event.data);
                console.log(message);

            });
            return wrappedWebSocket;
        }
    });

    window.WebSocket = webSocketProxy;
}
interceptWebSocket();
```

Comment: что значит _зацепиться на некий WebSocket_? Что указано в манифесте? Работают ли вообще скрипты из `contentscript`?

Comment: На сайте открыто сокет соединение. Через него между страницей и, так понимаю, каким то сервером передаются данные. Мне нужно их перехватить, обработать и отправить. Манифест приложу чуть позднее. Скрипты из contentscript работают, не работает лишь обработчик и подмена сокет соединения. Но полностью идентичный скрипт работает в TamperMonkey

Comment: Отредактируй вопрос, добавив необходимую информацию запрошенную в первом комментарии и [mcve] твоего скрипта, который работает в тампермонкей. Отредактировать вопрос можно с помощью кнопки [edit] под вопросом

Comment: Я не поверю что этот скрипт может работать в TamperMonkey. Ибо перехватить конфиденциальные данные сокета путем подмены в расширении невозможно. Достать данные из сокета можно только через DevTools, но это уже не обычное расширение, и скрыть подмену от пользователя так же невозможно.

Comment: Прикрепил листинги манифеста и функции из контент скрипта, отвечающей за вебсокет

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg Тем не менее оно правда работает. Скрипт в TamperMonkey спокойно перехватывает данные, обрабатывает их и отправляет.

Comment: Если необходимо подтверждение работы данной функции в TamperMonkey, я могу записать небольшой видеоролик с захватом экрана.

Comment: Возможно, вы меня неправильно поняли. Данный код исполняется в contentScript, а он же имеет доступ к области сайта?

Comment: Ты нигде не вызываешь функцию `interceptWebSocket`

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gwOoSy4MtDU
Вот, вывод в консоль информации, полученной с сокета через ContentScript при помощи TamperMonkey

Comment: @Grundy, это был фрагмент кода - функции. Весь полный код, используемый мной, займет слишком много места, чтобы его публиковать

Comment: Опубликовал скрипт из TamperMonkey, который был показан на видеозаписи.

Comment: @Никита Вот ссылка на [Chrome DOC](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#isolated_world), а вот на [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#content_script_environment), где сказано что мы работаем в изолированных мирах. Но я только что прочитал про manifest3, который никогда не пробовал. Попробуй добавить это ["world"- MAIN](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/content_scripts/#world-timings). Похоже это должно пересечь твой скрипт со скриптом страницы. Заодно расскажешь, мне так же интересно.

Comment: @Никита Я уже сам попробовал, действительно с параметром `"world": "MAIN"` работает, [вот фотка](https://disk.yandex.ru/i/BvkMgksGOfYlhQ)

Comment: И правда, дело было в изоляции. Спасибо)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Благодаря ответу @AlexanderLonberg получилось разобраться в вопросе.
Как говорил Александр, `contentScript` имеют свои выделенные контейнеры для выполнения в области сайта, и не могут пересекаться со скриптами самого сайта. Для решения надо добавить `"world": "MAIN"` в раздел `contentScripts` манифеста расширения, разрешив скриптам выполняться в основной области сайта. Подробнее о контейнерах скриптов [тут](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#isolated_world) и [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#content_script_environment). Про раздел манифеста [тут](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/content_scripts/#world-timings)